# Placing UiView as a subview programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have ViewController that looks like this. There is parent ScrollView that holds UIView (wrapperView) and this wrapper view has TextView and ImageView inside.
This simple structure is created form interface builder with all constraints needed so it works fine.

[image]

In some cases I need to programmatically add one more UIView inside my wrapperView right under ImageView (green arrow points there).

So I created xib file for my new UIView and separate class for it

```
class MyView : UIView {
    class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
        return UINib(nibName: "MyView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    }
}
```

And I code of my ViewController I added

```
let myView = MyView.instanceFromNib()
myView = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 80)
wrapperView.addSubview(myView)
```

now i see myView on the screen in top of wrapperView but when i try to apply constraints like

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: myImageView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8).isActive = true
```

I got

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` of `myView` to `false`?

Comment: You need to update `UIScrollView` content size after adding a new view. try calling `layoutIfNeeded()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set this:

```
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

And then you have to make sure that there are no your own constraints that are in conflict. In storyboard you have probably added a constraint that binds `imageView.bottomAnchor` to `wrapperView.bottomAnchor`. Now if you put between these two anchors another view, you need to deactivate that constraint.

Otherwise if you try to squeeze `myView` there, it may result in constraint conflicts - imagine there is a constraint saying that

1. `imageView.bottomAnchor` should be 10 points from `wrapperView.bottomAnchor`,

but there are also two more constraints saying that

2. `imageView.bottomAnchor` should be 10 points from `myView.topAnchor` and `myView.bottomAnchor` should be 10 points from `wrapperView.bottomAnchor`.

Obviously both these scenarios cannot be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the easiest solution would be add an UIStackView to the wrapperView in the interface builder with no height, just add needed constraints (top, left, bottom, right).  Then drag an IBOutlet of the UIStackView to your ViewController and when you will need to add a subview:

```
@IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!

func someFunc() {
  let myView = MyView.instanceFromNib()
  myView = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 80)
  stackView.addArrangedSubview(myView)
}
```

UIStackView will change its size based on its subviews.

Answer (score -1):

You may use the Debug View Hierarchy to debug your UI issues including the constraints which are failing to be satisfied. Most probably your `.top` constraint which is added at runtime is conflicting with `.top` constraint which you have set in your storyboard.